# "LAG could not take such arguments" warning in IntelliJ IDEA for correct usage of function

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

Given the MariaDB query `SELECT LAG(value, 1) OVER (ORDER BY added_on) FROM transactions`. I'm working in IntelliJ IDEA (could as well be PHPStorm anything JetBrains related), and my IDE gives me an error for the `LAG` function, namely:

> LAG could not take such arguments

Removing the `, 1` in the `LAG` function removes this warning, but why am I given this warning in the first place? According to [documentation](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lag-function/), this is a perfectly fine way to call `LAG(<expression>[,offset]) OVER (ORDER BY <expression>)`

Edit: Screenshot of message
[image]

Comment: Your question says MySQL / MariaDB  which are you using and please publish full error message,and the versions you are on.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e45966415d65ead69f9b72367c973f18

Comment: @P.Salmon see screenshot of error message. I cannot reproduce the error myself as well, the query runs just fine when executed, it's just the IDE that thinks it's not proper behaviour. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 (Ultimate Edition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we need to update our code assistance hints for MySQL. [Here is issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-14796) on our tracker, please follow and vote.